# CSS - Let text come from left when Button extends parallel to the buttons right border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Button that expands and I want the text of the Button to move in parallel with the right border of the button until the button is expended to maximum width. So the text is invisible right when the button is collapsed and moves in from the left to the right.

Currently I just have the expending button. For illustration it is an endless loop.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("myButton");

const toggleClass = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      button.className = button.classList.contains('btn1') ? 'btn btn2' : 'btn btn1';
      setTimeout(toggleClass, 100);
  }, 1500);
}

toggleClass();
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.btn2 {
  max-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='myButton' class='btn btn1'>Some text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/579357/

Also, you can run the snippet here:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("myButton");

const toggleClass = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      button.className = button.classList.contains('btn1') ? 'btn btn2' : 'btn btn1';
      setTimeout(toggleClass, 100);
  }, 1500);
}

toggleClass();
```

```css
.btn { 
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  right: 5px; 
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.btn1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
}


.btn2 {
  max-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='myButton' class='btn btn1'><span>Some text</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I came to the conclusion that i didn't ask the question correctly. Maybe you take a look again.

Comment: Check this one now.